# Problem in PIC24FJ128GA202 UART?

Tags: pic, c, uart

I started to work on PIC24FJ128GA202 microcontroller. Tried samples programs like LED blink and switch, controller works fine with the coding, then I started to work on UART configured all the parameters  as per datasheet norms. But my PIC is not functioning to my code. I have connected my controller to PC to check the characters transferred . I have posted my code below. I don't receive any character on hyperterminal... Some times I received garbage values.

```
#include "p24FJ128GA202.h"              // Pic24FJ128GA202 header file
#define led PORTAbits.RA2 

void init_processor(void);

void init_processor(void)
{
    /* oscillator configuration is pending*/
    OSCCON = 0x0000;
    CLKDIV   =  0x0000;  //do not divide
    OSCTUN = 0; 
    RPINR18bits.U1RXR   = 7; //UART1 receive set to RB7
    RPOR4bits.RP8R  =   3;   //UART1 transmit set to RB8
    __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON & 0xbf); //clear the bit 6 of OSCCONL to
                                       //unlock Pin Re-map
   RPOR4bits.RP8R = 3;
   //__builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | 0x40); //set the bit 6 of OSCCONL to
                                        //lock Pin Re-map
    // configure digital pins
    ANSA = 0x0000;
    ANSB = 0x0000;
    //  assign  IO values for ports
    PORTA = 0x0000;
    TRISA = 0x0000;
    PORTB = 0x0000;
    TRISB = 0x0000;   // 7 as receive and 8 as transmitter

    // Init UART1
    U1MODE = 0x0000;
    U1STA = 0x0400;     //Enable Transmission, Clear all flags
    U1BRG = 25;
    U1MODEbits.UARTEN = 1;        // And turn the peripheral on
}

void uart1tx(char in_c)
{
    while(U1STAbits.UTXBF != 0);
    U1TXREG = in_c;
}

void uart1str(char *s)
{
    while(*s!='\0')
    {
        uart1tx(*s);
        s++;
    }
}

char uart1rx()
{
    char c;
    while(U1STAbits.URXDA == 0); 
    c = U1RXREG;
    return c;   
}

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    led = 1;
    init_processor();
    while(1)
    {
        uart1tx('A');
        led = ~led;
        for(j=0;j<250;j++)
        {
            for(i=0;i<1275;i++);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're getting garbage, then your UART baudrate on both sides is not equal! They need to be.

Comment: Do you have 'scope? If yes, probe the serial data coming out of the PIC. Set up an infinite loop sending one character with a little delay. 'U' is nice because its 0x10101010 - easy to look at on the scope. Then check your bit widths to see whether your baud rate is correct. Then check number and presence of start/stop bits.

Comment: Do you have an inverting driver between the chip and the PC?

Comment: ya, i have max 3232 converter between pic and pc. i just made a small change in a program. From hyperterminal i transmitted a character  and received it on pic Uc. if received char  is 'T' led will blink.. Else  led is off... only problem is transmitting a character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unlock the PPS prior to making changes. Specifically, the

```
__builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON & 0xbf);
```

must be moved above

```
RPINR18bits.U1RXR   = 7;
```

Also, you probably want to use MC macros to do this. Here is an example of working UART init for similar micro -> https://github.com/felis/cdb/blob/master/fw/minimal/bsp.c#L185